# From an image, how do I determine the shade?

Tags: database, image, colors, compare, photoshop

For a database app I'm trying to determine the average shade of a section of photo, against a colour scale.

Being a novice I'm finding this very difficult to explain so I've created a simple diagram showing exactly what I'm trying to achieve.

http://www.knockyoursocksoff.com/shade/

If anybody has the time to give me some ideas I'd be very grateful.

Best wishes,

Warren.

Comment: What languages do you have available to determine the shade of the image (Java, C, C++, etc.)? ANSI SQL can't do this, so you need some other application running as a CRON job or something of the sort to do this.  For C, there is always OpenCV: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/

Comment: openCV looks interesting. never heard of it before, but I've been trying to programatically get images off a camera, and it looks like just the thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using color photos, you should first convert the selected area from RBG (red, green, blue) to HSL/HSV ([article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)).

HSL stands for "hue, saturation, lightness".<sup>1</sup> The number you are interested in is the *lightness*.

In the most general terms, the lightness refers to how you perceive the brightness of a colored surface. It's hard to use the red/green/blue components to say whether a patch of red is brighter/darker than, say, a patch of blue. Converting to HSL takes care of that problem.

Once you have done the conversion, you can simply average the lightness values of your selected area.

*Quick note on lightness values: Technically, you can't simply average the lightness values because the perception of lightness is not linear ([article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightness_%28color%29)). But, unless you are writing a deeply scientific application, simply averaging the lightness will give you an "accurate enough" value.*

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>*In Adobe Photoshop, they call it HSB (hue, saturation, brightness)*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I think I would start by just averaging the pixel values:

```
for x = start_x to end_x
for y = stary_y to end_y
  total += getPixel(x,y)
shade = total / (xlen*ylen)
```

Its going to be more complicated if you're doing it in color.